# Свойство "overflow"

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Я уже гуглил на счёт этого свойства, я вроде-бы понимаю смысл его действия, но не всегда. 
Объясните: что оно конкретно делает з **float** элементами, а что с обычными.
Но сперва взгляните [сюда](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar). Почему, если убрать свойство overflow - всё пропадёт, каким образом оно тут что-то решает. 
Буду благодарен за ответ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

overflow работает одинаково с блоками и не зависит от способа их позиционирования.
В вашем примере если убрать у navbar свойство `overflow` происходит его схлопывание из за float елементов внутри и отсутствия clearfix  у navbar.